# numpy.column_stack vectorized

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I would like to vectorize some code, but I find it hard to apply some functions to vectors of variables.

For example, I have two constant vectors, `a` and `b`, and a vector of vectors `x` (a matrix). Dimensions of the members of `x` is the same as those of a and b. I want to make matrices formed by columns from : a member of `x`, `a`, and `b`:

```
x = [[ 0.76662363 -0.0397725   0.64086377]
 [ 0.76198581 -0.04605764  0.6459538 ]]

a = [ 0.2763932   0.85065081 -0.5527864 ]

b = [-0.7236068   0.52573111 -0.5527864 ]
```

The output should be a vector (or array) of two 3x3 matrices. I am trying to run the following code:

```
a = np.column_stack((x, a, b))
```

however I get an error message that the dimensions do not match across the arguments:

```
File "/software/python/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 317, in column_stack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add sample input and the expected output. Furthermore add the stacktrace of your error.

Comment: How do you rearrange 12 terms (2x3,3,3) into 18 terms (2 3x3)?

Comment: hpaulj, by taking 2 copies of a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with the updated requirements:

```
>>> N = 2    # n cols of x.T
>>> K = 3    # x and a and b
>>> M = 3    # len(a)
>>> outstack = np.empty((N, M, K))
>>> outstack[..., 0] = x
>>> outstack[..., 1] = a[None, :]
>>> outstack[..., 2] = b[None, :]
```

outstack stacks two 3x3 matrices.

The trick here is preallocating the output stack. The output serves as a broadcasting reference, so `a` and `b` can be used almost unchanged and will be broadcast correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me a single matrix which has dimension 3 x 4, and whose two first columns are x.T, and the latter two columns are a and b. What I want is two 3x3 matrices, one for each element of x.

Comment: @John you mean you want two copies of x.T one with a joined as the third column, one with b?

Comment: No. I need two 3x3 matrices. If x1 and x2 are the two rows of x (columns of x.T), the two matrices I need are:
(x1 a b)
(x2 a b)

The reason I need to vectorize the code is that the members of x are 10^8, instead of 2.

Comment: John - you should have put that basic information in the question the first time.

Comment: hpaulj, noted. I assumed that using the term vectorize would do the trick.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to 'speedup'? `[np.column_stack((i,a,b)) for i in x]`

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: You'll need to `tile` or `repeat` the 3 arrays so they can be concatenated into one (2,3,3) array.

Comment: @John I think I finally worked out what you want. My approach is to preallocate the target array. The advantage this brings is that it serves as a broadcasting reference, so no repeating or tiling required. Could you please check whether it does the correct thing?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, this does the trick indeed. Many thanks. Is this the fastest way to do it? I will probably need to open a new question, but can I use outstack in np.linalg.solve (outstack, c) where c is a single vector?

Comment: @John My hunch is it should be one of the fastest but I'm absolutely no expert on this. hpaulj is better at that sort of question. I doubt (but don't know for sure) `linalg.solve` is vectorised in that way. I think you are a bit out of the mainstream use-case-wise ;-) But you could ask a new question regarding the solver, people may find that interestinig.

Comment: In compiled code, `concatenate` does this sort of assignment - create the `out` array, and copy the inputs to the correct slots.

Comment: @hpaulj could you elaborate? Is your method faster?